# Given the following vector $X$, find a non-zero square matrix $A$ such that $AX=\vec{0}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am incredibly confused at this question and have been trying it for multiple hours with different numbers but i cant see to get anything except for $X=\vec{0}$. I am given

$$X = \left(\begin{array}{c} 7\\ 7\\5\end{array}\right)$$

What is $A$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Some possibilities for rows of $A$ are $[1\ -\!\!1\ 0]$, $[0\ 5\ -\!\!7]$, $[1\ 4\ -\!\!7]$, and the transpose of any vector perpendicular to $X$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The goal is to find combinations of 3 numbers $a,b,c$ such that $7a+7b+5c=0$, which in vector form is the same as $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a&b&c\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}7\\7\\5\end{array}\right)=0$. There are many possible combinations. Then, each combination you find is a possible row of matrix $A$. Select 3 combinations and you are done.